# Unable to set correct npm config for group registry

Tags: npm, gitlab, .npmrc

I have two npm packages that are private repositories hosted on gitlab.com under a group organization.
My first package lives well and get updated and downloaded by users of the same organisation.

To install a private scoped package, the [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/index.html#authenticate-with-a-personal-access-token-or-deploy-token) says:

```
# Set URL for your scoped packages.
# For example package with name `@foo/bar` will use this URL for download
npm config set @foo:registry https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<your_project_id>/packages/npm/
```

So my `.npmrc` looked like

```
@mygroup:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<id-project-1>/packages/npm/
//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<id-project-1>/packages/npm/:_authToken=<token>
//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<id-project-2>/packages/npm/:_authToken=<token>
//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=<token>
```

Obviously, everything works fine for the first package but not for the second one.

What I can't understand is **why a scoped package should refer to a unique project url**?

Because of this, I can't install both of my packages: the url of my scoped packages will only be valid for one of them.

I looked at the api endpoint to return a list of my group's packages I found this:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/packages.html#within-a-group

So I updated my `.npmrc` to

```
@mygroup:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/mygroup/packages/npm/
//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<id-project-1>/packages/npm/:_authToken=<token>
//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<id-project-2>/packages/npm/:_authToken=<token>
//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=<token>
```

But it doesn't work.
On the `group/group-id/packages` route I only get gitlab infos but nothing in an npm friendly format.

How to install more than one private scoped npm package hosted under the same group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance level endpoint seems answer to your situation [instance-level-npm-endpoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/#instance-level-npm-endpoint)

Using:

```
npm config set @mygroup:registry https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/packages/npm/
npm config set -- '//gitlab.example.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken' "<your_token>"
```

You should be able to publish `@mygroup/project1` & `@mygroup/project2`

Comment: I totally missed this one, thanks!

Comment: I tried this as well now in 2022 and this does not seem to work. We have multiple packages from 2 projects and using the instance level npm endpoint still end up with a 404

Answer (score 2):

I experienced some troubles using yarn (`1.22.10`) so I'll post more details here just to save couple of hours to anybody reading this.

For some unknown reasons I was able to install the package with npm but not with yarn and I got `Request failed \"404 Not Found\"`

I ended up by creating a `.npmrc` file at the root of the project (I'm working with docker) with the following content:

```
@my-org:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/
//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=<GITLAB_TOKEN_API_SCOPE>
//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<ID_PROJECT_1>/packages/npm/:_authToken=<GITLAB_TOKEN_API_SCOPE>
//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<ID_PROJECT_2>/packages/npm/:_authToken=<GITLAB_TOKEN_API_SCOPE>
```

**Line 3 and 4 are required for `yarn`** but not for `npm`.

To make it work replace `@my-org` by your gitlab organisation name, `gitlab.com` by the url where your projects are, `<ID_PROJECT_X>` by the ids of the projects you want to install and `<GITLAB_TOKEN_API_SCOPE>` by a personal token with an API scope.